# Java: How to fix "String index out of range: #"?

Tags: java, string, methods

I'm attempting to scramble two random letters of a string which isn't the first letter, or last two. I'm getting a "String index out of range" error when compiling. I've tried workshopping many different solutions, but nothing seems to work.

For this assignment, we have to use a method and .charAt commands. I've tried creating variables for the two random characters then adding them back into the string flipped, but couldn't get that to work either.

```
public static String scramble(String input) {
    int range = input.length() - 3;
    int place = (int)(Math.random() * range);
    String newWord = "";
    newWord = input.substring(0, place);
    newWord = newWord + newWord.charAt(place) + 2;
    newWord = newWord + newWord.charAt(place) + 1;

    return newWord;
```

I'm expecting an output of a string with two of its characters scrambled. For example, "Fantastic" would be "Fantsatic", or "Fnatastic".

Comment: Make sure the "place" value is not greater than string length before you call .chartAt

Comment: Why do you get the error while compiling ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public static String scramble(String input) {
    int range = input.length() - 3;
    int place = (int)(Math.random() * range);
    String newWord = input.substring(0, place);
    newWord = newWord + input.charAt(place + 1);
    newWord = newWord + input.charAt(place);
    // if you need the whole input, just 2 characters exchanged, uncomment this next line
    // newWord = newWord + input.substring(place + 2, range);
    return newWord;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do :

```
newWord = input.substring(0, place);
```

So the indexes inside `newWord` goes from `0` to `place-1`
Then you do:

```
newWord.charAt(place);
```

But this index does not exist in your String. It is `Out of Bound`

See [the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int))

Answer (score 0):

When you create `newWord = input.substring(0, place)` it has exactly `place` characters. You can't request `charAt(place)` from it, the last character is at `place-1`.

If you want to swap characters convert input to `char[]` and generate random indexes to swap.

```
String input = "Fantastic";

// random constraints
int min = 1;
int max = input.length() - 3;

// random two characters to swap
int from = min + (int) (Math.random() * max);
int to;
do {
    to = min + (int) (Math.random() * max);
} while (to == from); // to and from are different

// swap to and from in chars
char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
char tmp = chars[from];
chars[from] = chars[to];
chars[to] = tmp;
String result = new String(chars);

System.out.println(result); // Ftntasaic
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
  public static String scramble(String input) {
    if(input.length() >3){
        int range = input.length() - 3;
        int place  = 1+   new Random().nextInt(range) ;
        input=input.substring(0, place) +input.charAt(place  + 1)+input.charAt(place) +input.substring( place+2);

    }
    return input;
}
```

input: Fantastic
output : Fanatstic  ,  Fatnastic   ,Fanatstic